Selenium Does not work when it is advertised
I do not understand what the error is. I declare driver as a variable for webdriver.chrome() but even at this stage I have already encountered an error, the functions are not executed further than this line. Here are the code and errors:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome()

Error
Warning:'chrome' is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.chrome()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I tried reinstalling the drivers, browser, Selenium, and python and adding the driver to the environment variables.

The problem is that you haven't capitalized Chrome().
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
                   ^
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

There are probably hundreds of thousands of Selenium users. Before you start blaming Selenium, perhaps check some tutorials and make sure that you've followed them accurately.
